# Turbolinks equivalent event to window.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a rails web application that uses [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to arrange images on the page. I activate Masonry like so:

```
var masonry_load = function(){...};
$(window).on('load', masonry_load);
```

Using `window.load` instead of `document.ready` ensures that the images have been loaded, which is necessary to ensure Masonry can arrange them nicely (their heights vary).

However, I haven't been able to find an equivalent event to use within Turbolinks. Trying to use Turbolinks' `document.page:load` behaves the same as `document.ready`; namely, the thumbnails are not arranged properly, because Masonry tries to start without knowing the image dimensions.

Is there an event in Turbolinks that is fired when all the content in the new body has been loaded, similar to the way that `window.load` behaves for a normally-loaded page?

Comment: Use jQuery Turbolinks - https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Comment: by `document.page:load` you mean `$(window).on('page:load', masonry_load);` right?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: @elsurudo no, I no longer work on the project where I needed this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() { /* ... */ });
```

More info: [Turbolinks Documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/README.md#full-list-of-events)